# Multiple Nav, header and aside

Tags: html, css

How would my code look for the following layout? How do I create multiple nav and headers in HTML?

[image: Grid Layout]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply use `grid-template-areas` to set your layout:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "headerA headerB headerB headerB headerB"
    "headerA navB navB navB navB"
    "navA article article article aside"
    "footer footer footer footer footer";
}

.header-1 {
  grid-area: headerA;
}

.header-2 {
  grid-area: headerB;
}

.nav-1 {
  grid-area: navA;
}

.nav-2 {
  grid-area: navB;
}

.article {
  grid-area: article;
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

/* for styling puropse only */
body {
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

body > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px lightgrey;
}

.article {
  min-height: 102px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-1">Header 1</div>
<div class="header-2">Header 2</div>
<div class="nav-1">Navigation Bar 1</div>
<div class="nav-2">Navigation Bar 1</div>
<div class="article">Article</div>
<div class="aside">Aside</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```